# Getting Info logs from zygote64

Tags: android, logging, jit

Im getting logs from zygote64 on my phone and its making debugging hard for me. Is there any way I can disable it?

[image: Logs]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to filter log messages in Logcat. Create a new filter (Edit Filter Configurations) with this **Log Tag** using a regular expression (REGEX option must be enabled):

```
^(?!(zygote64))
```